# .filter return empty array but same condition work with .map

Tags: javascript, react-native, search, filter

I'm doing a simple search bar on react native

I've got some dummy NftDatas that look like this :

```
[
  { name: "Lorem ipsum", ... },
  { name: "dolor sit amet", ... },
  { name: "consectetur adipiscing", ... },
  { name: "elementum dolor", ... },
  { name: "sapien eu porttitor", ... },
]
```

I've got a `handleSearch()` function which compare the user input to the names in the list :

```
const handleSearch = (value) => {
    const filteredData = NFTData.filter((item) => {
      item.name.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase());
    });

    console.log(filteredData);
};

//Return an empty array no matter what value the user inputted
```

But if I map the array and verify the exact same condition it works perfectly fine :

```
const handleSearch = (value) => {
    let filteredData2 = [];

    NFTData.map((item) => {
      if (item.name.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())) {
        filteredData2.push(item.name);
      }
    });

    console.log(filteredData2);
};

// For user input "lor" return ["Lorem ipsum", "dolor sit amet", etc ...]
```

Even if my app now works fine I wonder what I did wrong with my .filter function

Comment: Please do not use `.map()` for simple array iteration. Use `.forEach()` or a normal loop to do that.

Comment: I just wanted to know why my .filter return nothing while It should, but thanks anyway It will still improve my code

Comment: you need to return a boolean from your `filter` function. add a `return` or remove the curly braces

Comment: `const filteredData = NFTData.filter((item) => 
      item.name.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase());
    );` will work

Comment: Thanks a lot @R4ncid that's exactly the anwser I was looking for